# How can i dynamically fetch different defined settings form wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm making a plugin that will access a resource on different accounts.
I have made entries in wp-config.php as folow:

```
define('account_key_1','3452345dfg')
define('secret_1','123123')
define('account_key_2','3452345dfg')
define('secret_2','123123')
```

I would like to get the account detail into a variable based on a plugin shortcode settings
like
[myplugin account="1"]
would make the code use account 1
I have setup the code to get the value of the shortcode tag and it works and echo $account print whatever i put in the shortcode under account.

I have tryed to use

```
$key= accout_key_.$account
```

Put that sent it to "account_key_1"
if i do

```
$ket= account_key_1;
```

it works, but i would like to change the ket number dynamically based on the shortcode.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question wasn't that clear for me but based on your example, the below will print `3452345dfg`

```
$account = 2;
$key = constant('account_key_'.$account);
echo $key;
```

[Reference](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-constant-value-dynamically/)

Comment: Yupp, that works!!! Thanks a bunch!!!
`$key= constant('account_key_'.$account);`
Did the trick